# Cover Helper Class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have a class that I wrote that maps dates to specific fields on a custom object and that is it. How would you test this if there are no dml statements? How would you assert that a value is correct? Do you even need to write a test for it, because it shows 0% coverage now so that makes me think I should? Example:

```
public with sharing class UpdaterHelper {
public static Map<Date, SObjectField> dateToField = new Map<Date, SObjectField>
{
    Date.newInstance(2014, 10, 1) => Revenue_Pipeline__c.Oct2014__c,
    Date.newInstance(2014, 11, 1) => Revenue_Pipeline__c.Nov2014__c,
    Date.newInstance(2014, 12, 1) => Revenue_Pipeline__c.Dec2014__c,
    Date.newInstance(2015, 01, 1) => Revenue_Pipeline__c.Jan2015__c
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd spot-check it to make sure the collection is initialised:

```
System.assertEquals(
        Revenue_Pipeline__c.Dec2014__c,
        UpdaterHelper.dateToField.get(Date.newInstance(2014, 12, 1))
        );
```

Whether that registers as coverage or not is not really important.

Comment: It should count as coverage-- the only requirement is that the class is referenced in the code, which will trigger the static initialization assignment. Your "unit test" should result in 100% coverage of those lines.